# Find $\int_0^\infty \sqrt{x} \left( \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{x+a}{c} \right)- \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{x-a}{c} \right) \right)dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

How to compute the integral
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\sqrt{x}\left[\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+a}{c} \right)- \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{x-a}{c} \right) \right]\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
for $c,a>0$.
If the it the integration is to difficult can we give a good upper bound?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using integration by parts, the given integral equals
$$ \frac{2}{3}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{4ac x^{5/2}}{\left(a^2+c^2-2 a x+x^2\right) \left(a^2+c^2+2 a x+x^2\right)}\,dx $$
and by substituting $x=z^2$, this integral becomes
$$ \frac{2}{3}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{4ac z^{6}}{\left(a^2+c^2-2 a z^2+z^4\right) \left(a^2+c^2+2 a z^2+z^4\right)}\,dz $$
where the integrand function is $O\left(\frac{1}{|z|^2}\right)$ as $|z|\to +\infty$. By the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem), we just need to compute the residues of the integrand function at the poles in the upper half-plane, given by $\sqrt{\pm a+ ic}$ and $-\sqrt{\pm a-ic}$. It follows that the given integral equals:

$$\boxed{ \frac{2\pi}{3}\sqrt{c(3a^2-c^2)+(a^2+c^2)\sqrt{a^2+c^2}} }$$
and a simple upper bound (that is tight iff $a\approx 0$ or $a\approx c\sqrt{3}$) is given by $\color{red}{\frac{2\pi\sqrt{2}}{3}(a^2+c^2)^{3/4}}$.

Comment: @Lisa: no. If $x=z^2$, then $dx = 2z\,dz$. The factor $2$ is absorbed by the change of the integration range from $\mathbb{R}^+$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I noticed it after I asked this.  Thank you for a beautiful approach.

Comment: Why are we only computing polls in the upper half-plane? I know this has to do with how you construct the path of integration in complex plane.

Comment: @Lisa: because such integral is the limit as $R\to +\infty$ of the integral of the same function in the complex plane, with the integration path being a half-circle centered at the origin in the upper half-plane. The contribute given by the integral along the arc vanishes as $R\to +\infty$ due to $f(z)=O\left(\frac{1}{|z|^2}\right)$.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. This part is clear.   Another, question when you combine $\arctan$'s you get $\tan^{-1} \frac{2ac}{c^2+x^2-a^2}$, right?  But then the derivative of this is $ \frac{d}{dx} \tan^{-1} \frac{2ac}{c^2+x^2-a^2} = \frac{4a c x}{(c^2+x^2-a^2)^2+(2ac)^2}=\frac{4acx}{(a^2-2ac+c^2+x^2)(a^2+2ac+c^2+x^2)}$. For some reason my denominator is different then yours. Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: @Lisa: it is easier to first differentiate both arctangents, then factoring the difference of such derivatives.

Comment: Can you also give a little detail on how you compute the residues?

Comment: @Lisa: the poles are simple, hence the residues can be computed through: $$\text{Res}\left(\frac{f(z)}{g(z)},z=z_0\right) = \lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{(z-z_0)f(z)}{g(z)} = \frac{f(z_0)}{g'(z_0)}.$$

Comment: Sure. But how do you get such a nice expression at the end. When I do this my expression is very messy.

Comment: For example, for $z_0=\sqrt(a+ic)$ I get that the residue is   $Res= \frac{(a+ic)^{3-\frac{3}{2}}}{16 i ac}$. Is this correct?

Comment: @Lisa: it is. The remaining part is just simple algebra to simplify the sum of those residues.

Comment: Dea Jack after simplifications I arrive at $\sum Res(\cdot,z_k)= \frac{ (1+(-1)^{5/2} )}{16} \left( \frac{( -a+ ic)^{3/2}  }{  (a^2 - i a c - c^2)} + \frac{( a+ ic)^{3/2} }{  (a^2 + i a c - c^2)} \right)$.   Is this correct?  I can't seem to get the same expression as you?

Comment: @Lisa: I do not have my original computations anymore, but the point is that you have to get the sum of two conjugates at the end, since the integral is real.

Answer (score 0):

With the short hand $b=\sqrt{a^2+c^2}$ and the substitution $x=t^2$, the integral is

\begin{align}
I=& \ 2\int_0^\infty t^2\left( \tan^{-1} \frac{t^2+a}{c} - \tan^{-1} \frac{t^2-a}{c} \right)dt\\
\overset{ibp}=& \ \frac{4c}3 \int_0^\infty
\frac{2at^2-b^2}{t^4-2at^2+b^2}+ \frac{2at^2+b^2}{t^4+2at^2+b^2}\ dt\\
=& \ \frac{4c}3 \bigg(\frac{(2a-b)\pi}{2\sqrt{2(b-a)}}+ \frac{(2a+b)\pi}{2\sqrt{2(b+a)}} \bigg)\\
= &\ \frac{2\pi}3\left(2a\sqrt{b+c}-b \sqrt{b-c} \right)
\end{align}